# Replace after every fourth input value with space jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what i want to achieve is that after every fourth be replaced with space.
Like if i start writing on keypress on input 1234123412341234,
I want to achieve 1234 1234 1234 1234, when user types.

```
<input type="text" id="number" maxlength=19  />
```

And here is js

```
$('#number').on('keypress', function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 4) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 4) + ' '+this.value.slice(5, 9);
  }
```

So this code only creates one space after fourth, 1234 123412341234.
But how to do for the rest of input value ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery isn't the solution here, you can do this with standard JS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030727/replace-every-nth-character-from-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for

**Note** it bugs a bit when you type fast, i'm fixing it atm <-- **Should be fine**

```js
$(function(){
    $("input").keydown(function(){
        if ((($(this).val().length+1) % 5)==0){
            $(this).val($(this).val() + " ");
        }
    });        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use replace and look for four characters.

```js
console.log('1234123412341234'.replace(/.{4}/g, '$& '));
```

Comment: great solution.