# How to find and replace every nth character occurrence using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find and replace for example every third occurrence of 'x' character in string with regular expression?

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030727/replace-every-nth-character-from-a-string) but it addresses every fourth character but I need every "nth" occurrence of specific character in string.

I'm using JavaScript `replace()` method, this below example will change every x character to y:

```
replace(/\x/g, 'y')
```

But how can I write regex for question above?

Some random text for example, and expected result:

> I amx nexver axt hoxme on Sxundxaxs.

to:

> I amx nexver ayt hoxme on Sxundyaxs.

I can use JS `for` loop with `split()` and `join()` but solution with `replace()` method seams more elegant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/((?:[^x]*x){2}[^x]*)x/g, '$1y');
```

So if you are searching for every 3rd occurrence then use `n-1` between `{}` in above regex.

To build it dynamically use:

```js
let str = 'I amx nexver axt hoxme on Sxundxaxs';
let n = 3;
let ch = 'x';

let regex = new RegExp("((?:[^" +ch+ "]*" +ch+ "){" + (n-1) + "}[^" +ch+ "]*)" +ch, "g");

str = str.replace(regex, '$1y');

console.log(str);
//=> I amx nexver ayt hoxme on Sxundyaxs
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PqqIP/1)