# Create a dataframe from pipe delimited text file with no new line character

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a text file (.txt format) as below -

```
|1|NewYork|96|2|Chennai|84|3|Amsterdam|96|
```

I want to read this a data frame using pyspark so that, it is created as below

```
---------------
c0 | c1| c2
---------------
1 | NewYork|96
---------------
2 | Chennai |84
----------------
3 | Amsterdam |96
```

Basically I want to replace every 4th *pipeline*( *|* ) delimiter to *newline character* (*\n*) so that I can create the dataframe.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match every nth character using this regex `((?:[^c]*c){n-1}[^c]*)c` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097042/how-to-find-and-replace-every-nth-character-occurrence-using-regex). (c stands for any character).

Using above regex we can replace every 3rd `|` by `\n` (Ignoring first and last `|`)

```
df = spark.read.text("/path/to/file")

# Remove first and last | then replacing every 3rd | with \n
replaced_df = df.withColumn('value', regexp_replace('value', '^\||\|$', '')) \
     .select(regexp_replace('value','((?:[^\|]*\|){2}[^\|]*)\|','$1\n').alias('value'))

cols = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']

# Split the column by \n and explode the array column
replaced_df.select(explode(split('value', '\n'))) \
 .select(split('col','\|').alias('value')) \
 .select(*map(lambda c: col('value').getItem(cols.index(c)).alias(c),cols)).show()

+---+---------+---+
| c0|       c1| c2|
+---+---------+---+
|  1|  NewYork| 96|
|  2|  Chennai| 84|
|  3|Amsterdam| 96|
+---+---------+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to solve it:

#### Dataframe

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.read.text('/your_data_path/*.txt')

output_df = (df
             .withColumn('values', f.split(f.expr('substring(`value`, 2, length(`value`) - 2)'), '\|'))
             .selectExpr('TRANSFORM(SEQUENCE(1, SIZE(values), 3), i -> ' \
                         'STRUCT(values[i - 1] AS c0, values[i] AS c1, values[i + 1] AS c2)) AS values')
             .selectExpr('inline(values)'))

output_df.show()
```

#### RDD

```py
rdd = sc.textFile('/your_data_path/*.txt')


def split(text):
  text = text.strip('|')
  values = text.split('|')
  for i in range(0, len(values), 3):
    yield values[i:i+3]


df = (rdd
      .flatMap(split)
      .toDF('c0 string, c1 string, c2 string'))

df.show()
```

Output

```
+---+---------+---+
| c0|       c1| c2|
+---+---------+---+
|  1|  NewYork| 96|
|  2|  Chennai| 84|
|  3|Amsterdam| 96|
+---+---------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly diffrenet logic but still does the work:

```
ch="|1|NewYork|96|2|Chennai|84|3|Amsterdam|96|"
ch=ch[:-1] # You want to delete first |
ch=ch[1:] # You want to delete last |
j=0
cpt=0
for i in ch:
  if(i=="|"):
    j+=1
  if(j==3): # You replace every third | with \n
    ch=ch[:cpt]+"\n"+ch[cpt+1:]
    j=0
  
  cpt+=1
    
print(ch)

1|NewYork|96
2|Chennai|84
3|Amsterdam|96
```