# C# - How to find and replace every nth character occurrence using C# or regex? Conversion from Javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

***Find and replace every 3rd character occurrence in a given string and replace it with H***

For instance : *74Mercedes1980* should be *74HerHedHs1H80*

Can be done in C# or regex.

I found this Javascript code that does the same thing and would like to convert it into a C# code. Can you please assist ?

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097042/how-to-find-and-replace-every-nth-character-occurrence-using-regex)

```
str = str.replace(/((?:[^x]*x){2}[^x]*)x/g, '$1y');

let str = 'I amx nexver axt hoxme on Sxundxaxs';
let n = 3;
let ch = 'x';

let regex = new RegExp("((?:[^" +ch+ "]*" +ch+ "){" + (n-1) + "}[^" +ch+ "]*)" +ch, "g");

str = str.replace(regex, '$1y');

console.log(str);
//=> I amx nexver ayt hoxme on Sxundyaxs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture 2 non whitespace chars `\S` and match the 3rd non whitespace char.

In the replacement use the capture group followed by the character that you want in the replacement.

If you want to also match a space, you can use a dot `.` instead of `\S`

```js
let str = '74Mercedes1980';
let n = 3;
let ch = 'H';
let regex = new RegExp("(\\S{" + (n - 1) + "})\\S", "g");
str = str.replace(regex, `$1${ch}`);
console.log(str);
```

In C# you can write this as

```
var str = "74Mercedes1980";
var n = 3;
var ch = 'H';
var regex = new Regex("(\\S{" + (n - 1) + "})\\S");
str = regex.Replace(str, "$1" + ch);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output

```
74HerHedHs1H80
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Sgc42N)

Answer (score 0):

The hard coded example equates to

```
var re = new Regex("((?:[^x]*x){2}[^x]*)x");
var result = re.Replace("I amx nexver axt hoxme on Sxundxaxs", m => m.Groups[1] + "y");
```

Which can be rewritten as

```
var ch = 'x';
var n = 3;  
var str = "I amx nexver axt hoxme on Sxundxaxs";        
var re = new Regex("((?:[^" +ch+ "]*" +ch+ "){" + (n-1) + "}[^" +ch+ "]*)" +ch);
var result = re.Replace(str, m => m.Groups[1] + "y");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u8mJrn

Comment: Your above answer doesn't solve the issue. The Question is **Find and replace every 3rd character occurrence in a given string and replace it with H**  For instance : *74Mercedes1980*  should be **74HerHedHs1H80**